# jsp:include not resolving scriptlets in path

Tags: jsp

In our application we often include a sub-section of the page by pointing to a Spring REST controller, like this:

```
<jsp:include path="/xyz/data?id=<%=obj.theId%>"/>
```

It normally works but I am finding that in some cases the scriptlet is not resolved.

The outcome varies from page to page: sometimes the target controller complains of a missing parameter, other times the interpreter complains about the syntax.

Other scriptlets in the same page work fine; The issue seems to be only with the `jsp:include` tag.

Comment: what's `theId`? user input? maybe it was malformed?

Comment: @user7294900 'theId' is a field available to the page. If I try to print it displays the correct value. It seems like the scriptler is interpreted as plain text.